# RabbitMQ bind exchange in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I need to bind an exchange (amq.topic) with a specific queue in Python.
How I can do this?

Now I bind with the RabbitMQ's GUI.

[I'm refering to this TAB of Rabbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZQN6.png)

I've done only the binding of a queue with this code:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_logs', exchange_type='topic')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='coda-di-prova', exclusive=False)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_logs', queue=queue_name, routing_key="test.*")

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))


channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

What I need to add in my code in order to get this result?
[Result IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux8zw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe didn't understand the question. But it is enough to use `amq.topic`

```py
import pika


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()


result = channel.queue_declare(queue='coda-di-prova', exclusive=False)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.topic', queue=queue_name, routing_key="test.*")

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))


channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```